# Value of std::money_base::pattern for std::moneypunct facet is different with output of money value

Tags: c++, stl, locale

I'm trying figure out format of output of a negative money value for std::moneypunct facet.

```
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::locale loc{ "en_US.utf8" };
    std::cout << "Locale name: " << loc.name() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Part field none: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(std::money_base::none) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Part field space: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(std::money_base::space) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Part field symbol: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(std::money_base::symbol) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Part field sign: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(std::money_base::sign) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Part field value: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(std::money_base::value) << std::endl;

    const auto& fct = std::use_facet<std::moneypunct<char, true>>(loc);

    if (!std::has_facet<std::moneypunct<char, true>>(loc))
    {
        std::cout << "There is no facet!" << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }

    std::money_base::pattern neg_ptrn = fct.neg_format();
    std::cout << "Pattern negative format field 0: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(neg_ptrn.field[0]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Pattern negative format field 1: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(neg_ptrn.field[1]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Pattern negative format field 2: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(neg_ptrn.field[2]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Pattern negative format field 3: " << static_cast<uint32_t>(neg_ptrn.field[3]) << std::endl;

    std::cout.imbue(loc);
    std::cout << "Money value: " << std::showbase << std::put_money(-12345678.0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Locale name: en_US.utf8
Part field none: 120
Part field space: 32
Part field symbol: 36
Part field sign: 43
Part field value: 118
Pattern negative format field 0: 36
Pattern negative format field 1: 43
Pattern negative format field 2: 120
Pattern negative format field 3: 118
Money value: -$123,456.78
```

First value of std::money_base::pattern is std::money_base::symbol. The second one is std::money_base::sign. But the result of output for money value is -$123,456.78. The first one is sign, the second one is symbol.

Why it's so?

Comment: You read the international currency symbol format (using `std::moneypunct<char,true>`), and you display in locale format (using `std::put_money(-12345678.0)`), use `std::put_money(-12345678.0,true)` to display in international currency symbol.